# Get parameter "Start Week On"

Tags: ios, swift, calendar

I'm working on an application that uses the calendar and I would like to know how I get the configuration of the device's calendar the parameter "Start Week On"
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Calendar.current.firstWeekday` and if you need a name `Calendar.current.weekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.firstWeekday]`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. For example my default calendar it's Gregorian and the first day of the week it's Sunday (1), so if the user change "Settings>>Calendar>>Start Week On" to another day it is not reflected in Calendar.current.firstWeekday.